# Freeze columns A and B and row one in Ecxel

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I freeze the first row *(one)* and the first and second column *(A and B)* in Excel 2013? I've try to select rows one and two and columns A, B and C and select freeze but it doesn't work.

[image]